# checking input for positive number

Tags: java, loops, error-checking

So for my programming assignment the user has to enter the number of grades, but we have to check the input and return the proper error. The number has to be a positive number, and the program needs to differ between the error and give the proper response and loop it back until the right number is inputed.  I got the error checking part but I'm having trouble getting the program to continue to the next part. any help would be appreciated

```
do {
        System.out.println("Enter number of grades");
        if (input.hasNextInt()){
             numGrade = input.nextInt();

            if (numGrade < 0){
                 System.out.println("Your number of grades needs to positive! Try again");
                 count1++;
                 continue;
            }   
         }
        else{
            System.out.println("You did not enter a number! Try again");
            count1++;
            input.next();
            continue;
         }


}while (count1 > 0);
```

Comment: Share your error stacktrace

Comment: @BalwinderSingh the question seems to be related to logical error in flow and not exception/error.

Comment: You unconditionally increment count1 just before the end of the loop. It would be more obvious if you were to use an IDE to automatically indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
//use a boolean to tell the loop to continue or not
boolean cont = true;

do {


    System.out.println("Enter number of grades");

    if (input.hasNextInt()){

        numGrade = input.nextInt();

        //I assume 0 is a valid response (not a negative int)
        if (numGrade <= 0){
            System.out.println("Your number of grades needs to positive! Try again");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            cont = false;
            System.out.println("Your input is valid! Value entered is " + numGrade);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You did not enter a number! Try again");
                input.next();
                continue;
    }
}
while (cont);
```